# How to import excel file into mysql database uding php?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I want to upload userdata into mysql database. For that purpose I want to import excel data into mysql database using php. I have written the code. But I am facing an error. I am providing my code for reference. My code is as follows.

```
include 'config.php'; 
require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
$allowedExts = array("xls","xlsx");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);


if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)&& (in_array($extension, $allowedExts)))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"] ;
    $filetype=$_FILES["file"]["type"] ;
    $filesize=$_FILES["file"]["size"] ;
    $filetemp=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

         //////////////////////////   
            $row=0;
        $handle = fopen($filetemp, "r");

        $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
                $data->read($filetemp);
```

My code stop executing from this line :

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
```

And I am geetting this error on my screen :
php28E.tmp is not readable.

Please help me in this question.

Comment: Is the file actually a BIFF or OfficeOpenXML format Excel file, or is it a CSV file with an xls extension?

Comment: Is the fact that you're opening the file in the line above preventing Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader from reading the file itself? Why are you opening it anyway?

Comment: If you move your uploaded file and give it an xls extension, then can Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader actually read the file?

Comment: @Mark Baker The file which I need to import is purely Excel file not an CSV file which is stored in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use phpexcel instead, works perfectly and also supports all kind of spreadsheets formats and it's well documented.
Download it at [PhpExcel Home](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com).
There is a lot of tips and tutorials on google.

This code works for me:

```
<?php
$newPath = __DIR__.'/'.basename($_FILES['filepath']['tmp_name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filepath']['tmp_name'], $newPath);
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($newPath);
............................
```

Comment: Sorry, your problem it's about uploading file... but i see PhpExcel as a better solution tu manage excel files...

Comment: Who raise the error? PHP or your excel library, maybe your upload code it's ok and the problem it's your excel library couldn't read the excel format properly or your apache server need file permissions...

Comment: Yes ,yes are right. My problem is with excel library.

Comment: Can you provide me the link of tutorial for importing excel into mysql using php. please its very urgent.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP-manual says (http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

Files will, by default be stored in the server's default temporary directory, unless another location has been given with the upload_tmp_dir directive in php.ini.

[...]

Whatever the logic, you should either delete the file from the temporary directory or move it elsewhere.

[...]

You should move the uploaded file with [move_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), before you're working with it.